# Python - getting 0 in all rows in the first column of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

input :

```
     status = [] 
     status.append(User)
     print(CsvUser)
     final_CsvUser= pd.DataFrame([CsvUser],index=None)`
```

output of `final_CsvUser`:

```
    externalId  userName    emails        phoneNumbers    title     familyName  

0        1         1      Ben@ben.com     111-111-1111   Analyst      Ben 

0        2         2      notben@ben.com  222-222-2222   Analyst      notBen
```

output of `print(CsvUser)`:

```
{'externalId': 1, 'userName': 1, 'emails': 'Ben@ben.com', 'phoneNumbers': '111-111-111', 
'title': 'Analyst', 'familyName': 'Ben'},{'externalId': 2, 'userName': 2,
 'emails': 'notben@ben.com', 'phoneNumbers': '222-222-2222', 'title': 'Analyst',
 'familyName': 'notBen'}
```

I am converting this obj `CsvUser` to a dataframe and unexpectedly getting `0` to all the rows in the first column.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? please be more specific

Comment: replace `pd.DataFrame([CsvUser],index=None)` with `pd.DataFrame(CsvUser)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first column defaults to an index. Reset it to one of your existing columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(csv_user)
df.set_index('externalId', inplace=True)
df
```